# Multiprocessing Pytorch on AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, parallel-processing, pytorch

I am trying to use [`multiprocessing.Pipe`](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/parallel-processing-in-python-with-aws-lambda/) to parallelize a Pytorch-based code on AWS Lambda. I gain speed-ups by increasing the number of processes on my local machine but not on the Lambda.

**Question**: why is this happening and can it be fixed?

I wrote the code below to test parallelizing `n` matrix multiplications over `m` processes and I obtained these results using a Lambda with 10G of memory

```
Mode: 'torch'                 Lambda / Local

150 matrix mult on 1 processes: 9.3s / 21.7s
150 matrix mult on 2 processes: 9.9s / 15.3s
150 matrix mult on 3 processes: 9.9s / 18.1s
 
350 matrix mult on 1 processes: 15.6s / 41.9s
350 matrix mult on 2 processes: 16.0s / 25.4s
350 matrix mult on 3 processes: 16.2s / 25.5s
 
700 matrix mult on 1 processes: 27.8s / 79.8s
700 matrix mult on 2 processes: 28.4s / 45.7s
700 matrix mult on 3 processes: 28.8s / 41.7s
```

**Lambda specs:**

- 10GB memory
- Docker image: `public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9`
- Torch install: `pip3 install torch==1.12.0+cpu torchvision==0.13.0+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`

**Code**: The code can be run in three modes `torch`, `numpy`, `lists`, to perform the experiment doing matrix multiplication with torch, numpy or python's lists respectively. See below the code for my times for numpy and lists. (Note that the sizes of the matrices are arbitrarily chosen to get the processing times in the order of seconds but not minutes)

```py
import time
import math
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
import numpy as np
import torch 

def process_computation(batch, test_mode, rows, cols, process_id, conn):

    print(f"start process-id {process_id}")
    if "numpy" == test_mode:
        matrix = np.random.standard_normal((rows, cols))
        for _ in batch:
            vector = np.random.standard_normal(cols)
            vector =  matrix.dot(vector)

    if "torch" == test_mode:
        matrix = torch.rand((rows, cols))
        for _ in batch:
            vector = torch.rand(cols)
            vector = torch.matmul(matrix, vector)

    if "lists" == test_mode:
        matrix = list(range(cols * rows))
        for _ in batch:
            vector = list(range(cols))
            for r in range(0, len(matrix), cols):
                for entry in matrix[r: r + cols]:
                    entry * vector[entry % cols]

    conn.send(batch)
    print(f"end  process-id {process_id}")
    conn.close()


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    test_mode = event["test_mode"]
    n_processes = event['n_processes'] 
    n_matrix_mul = event["n_matrix_mul"]
    rows = event["rows"]
    cols = event["cols"]
    
    # Spread the number of matrix multiplications to the batches
    batch_size = math.ceil(n_matrix_mul/n_processes)
    batches = [range(batch_size) for _ in range(n_processes)]
    
    processes_start_time = time.time()

    # create a list to keep all processes and connections
    processes = []
    parent_connections = []

    for process_id in range(n_processes):            
        # create a pipe for communication
        parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
        parent_connections.append(parent_conn)

        # create the process, pass instance and connection
        process = Process(target=process_computation, args=(batches[process_id], 
                                                            test_mode, 
                                                            rows, 
                                                            cols, 
                                                            process_id, 
                                                            child_conn,))
        processes.append(process)
    
    # start all processes
    for process in processes:
        process.start()

    # retrieve results from all processes
    for conn in parent_connections:
        conn.recv()

    # compute and return parallelization time 
    processes_time = time.time() - processes_start_time
    
    return {"processes_time": processes_time}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    res = []
    event = {}
    event["test_mode"] = "torch"

    if "torch" in event["test_mode"]:
        event['rows'] = int(5*1e4)
        event['cols'] = int(1e4)
    elif "numpy" in event["test_mode"]:
        event['rows'] = int(1*1e5)
        event['cols'] = int(1e3)
    elif "lists" in event["test_mode"]:
        event['rows'] = int(5*1e3)
        event['cols'] = int(1e2)

    for n_matrix_mul in [150, 350, 700]:
        
        for n_processes in [1, 2, 3]:
            
            event['n_processes'] = n_processes
            event["n_matrix_mul"] = n_matrix_mul
  
            response = lambda_handler(event, None)
            processes_time = response["processes_time"]

            res.append(f"{n_matrix_mul} matrix mult on {n_processes} processes: {processes_time:.2f}s" )
        res.append(" ")

    print("\n\nLocal test\n")
    print(f'Times for mode: {event["test_mode"]}\n')
    for r in res:
        print(r)
```

Times for `lists` and `numpy` modes (looking consistent between Lambda and Local):

```
Mode: 'lists'                 Lambda / Local

150 matrix mult on 1 processes: 8.5s / 9.4s
150 matrix mult on 2 processes: 4.3s / 6.6s
150 matrix mult on 3 processes: 2.9s / 5.6s
 
350 matrix mult on 1 processes: 20.2s / 16.4s
350 matrix mult on 2 processes: 9.9s / 10.8s
350 matrix mult on 3 processes: 6.6s / 8.1s
 
700 matrix mult on 1 processes: 40.6s / 29.6s
700 matrix mult on 2 processes: 20.2s / 16.6s
700 matrix mult on 3 processes: 13.5s / 12.3s

Mode 'numpy'                  Lambda / Local

150 matrix mult on 1 processes: 6.1s / 9.8s
150 matrix mult on 2 processes: 6.6s / 9.6s
150 matrix mult on 3 processes: 6.5s / 9.8s

350 matrix mult on 1 processes: 8.5s / 13.1s
350 matrix mult on 2 processes: 9.5s / 13.2s
350 matrix mult on 3 processes: 9.3s / 13.4s
 
700 matrix mult on 1 processes: 14.9s / 20.5s
700 matrix mult on 2 processes: 15.3s / 20.3s
700 matrix mult on 3 processes: 15.0s / 20.0s
```